# libuv error creating echo server udp based

Tags: c, libuv

i am having an issue when i start listening from incoming messages,
server is stuck on uv_run, i had the server working but deleted the
file with the wrong file on compilation and now i am stuck =/
i am using libuv library and trying to make an echo server udp based

```
#define UDP_SERVER_PORT 8888

static void on_send(uv_udp_send_t* req, int status){
    free(req);
    if (status) {
        fprintf(stderr, "uv_udp_send_cb error: %s\n", uv_strerror(status));
    }
}
static void on_read(uv_udp_t *req, ssize_t nread, const uv_buf_t *buf,const struct sockaddr *addr,unsigned flags){
    puts(":::::ON READ::::::");
    (void)flags;
    if (nread < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Read error %s\n", uv_err_name(nread));
        uv_close((uv_handle_t*) req, NULL);
        free(buf->base);
        return;
    }
    if (nread > 0) {
        char sender[17] = { 0 };
        uv_ip4_name((const struct sockaddr_in*) addr, sender, 16);
        fprintf(stderr, "Recv from %s\n", sender);

        uv_udp_send_t* res = malloc(sizeof(uv_udp_send_t));
        uv_buf_t buff = uv_buf_init(buf->base, nread);
        printf("-> Message Received:\n- %s\n", buf->base);
        uv_udp_send(res, req, &buff, 1, addr, on_send);
    }
    free(buf->base);
}
static void alloc_buffer(uv_handle_t *handle, size_t suggested_size, uv_buf_t *buf){
    puts(":::::ALLOC BUFFER::::::");
    (void)handle;
    buf->base = malloc(suggested_size);
    bzero(buf->base , suggested_size);
    buf->len = suggested_size;
}
uv_udp_t* init_echo_udp_server(uv_loop_t *loop, const char* address, int port){
    puts(":::::INIT ECHO SERVER::::::");
    uv_udp_t *recv_socket = malloc(sizeof(uv_udp_t));
    struct sockaddr_in recv_addr;
    uv_ip4_addr(address, port, &recv_addr);
    uv_udp_init(loop, recv_socket);
    puts(":::::bind::::::");
    uv_udp_bind(recv_socket, (const struct sockaddr *)&recv_addr, UV_UDP_REUSEADDR);
    puts(":::::start::::::");
    uv_udp_recv_start(recv_socket, alloc_buffer, on_read);
    return recv_socket;
}
uv_loop_t *loop= 0;
int main(int argc, const char** argv){
    loop = uv_default_loop();
    uv_udp_t* udp_socket = init_echo_udp_server(loop, "0.0.0.0", UDP_SERVER_PORT);
    printf("----- SERVER LISTENING -----\n");
    printf("-> UDP port: %d\n", UDP_SERVER_PORT);
    uv_run(loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? And why are there so many questions today, where the asker doesn't say what the problem is?

Comment: the server starts to listen, but then it is stuck on uv_run, i have a client sending messages to port 8888 but the server doesn t read anything

Comment: @user253751 can u help?

Comment: Okay, well it's supposed to be stuck in uv_run, that's what uv_run *does*. Does it not call on_read?

Comment: Are you sure the bind succeeded?

Comment: @user253751 on_read is not called

Comment: @user253751 bind returns 0 meaning success